# xCode doesn't accept Development certificate neither Distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to create an 'Apple Development' Provisioning Profile but xCode doesn't accept and shows the following error message:

Signing certificate is invalid.
Signing certificate "Apple Development: Fabio Pereira dos Santos (USER ID)", serial number "<DVTSigningCertificateSerialNumber: 0x7fb59e1a2af0>", is not valid for code signing. It may have been revoked or expired.

But, the certificate is valid and was not revoked.

I also tried to create a new one of type 'iOS Distribution' but also shows the error message:
No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found
No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "TEAM ID" with a private key was found.

I tried another thing like 'Automatic Signing (Recommended by Apple Documentation)', xCode tries to create the certificate and the profile but also gives an error:

Status field:

Automatic signing failed
Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com and include the Update Signing report from the Report navigator. (I did this)

and a second error below this:
Signing certificate is invalid.
Signing certificate "Apple Development: Fabio Pereira dos Santos (USER ID)", serial number "<DVTSigningCertificateSerialNumber: 0x7fb59e1a2af0>", is not valid for code signing. It may have been revoked or expired.

Please heeeeeelp.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the clock was wrong. Just set the Automatic in Configurations and that's it.